# MySQL INT(x) versus INT(x+1)

Tags: mysql

What is the impact of declaring a field as `INT(x)` versus `INT(x+1)` in MySQL?  What happens if I try to enter `12345` into an `INT(4)` field?  What happens when I query it?

Comment: I have read the MySQL docs, I still don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's about the display width. You only see it when you use ZEROFILL.

As copied from [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

`M` indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum legal display width is 255. Display width is unrelated to the range of values a type can contain, as described in [Section 11.1.4, “Numeric Types”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). For floating-point and fixed-point types, `M` is the total number of digits that can be stored.

If you specify **ZEROFILL** for a numeric column, *MySQL* automatically adds the `UNSIGNED` attribute to the column.

Numeric data types that permit the `UNSIGNED` attribute also permit `SIGNED`. However, these data types are signed by default, so the `SIGNED` attribute has no effect.

Comment: Yes, I have read the doc.  I don't understand it, this is why I'm posting here.

Comment: @JDelage Read [this](http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/) page then. This has been written from a newbie's POV.

Comment: Thanks.  So it's just used for ZEROFILL?  If I don't use ZEROFILL, I should just leave it blank?

Comment: @JDelage Yep! You can always leave it to blank except its not advised for other data-types.